how to return results from batch apex to lwc
Currently im calling below apex class in lwc using wire it will show all data, when user add filters it will show filters data. In synchrounous we have rows limit 50k. But i want to process more than 50k records, Is there possible to call batch apex results in lwc?
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static List<Map<String, Object>> getReport(String fromDate,String toDate,String[] Bu){       
        List<String> BUlst = new List<String>();
        for (String buValue : BU) {
            BUlst.add(buValue);
        }
        String query='Select Revenue_Month__c,Revenue_Amount__c from Revenue_Report__c';
        String filter=' WHERE ID!=null';
        if(!BUlst.isEmpty()){
          filter+=' AND Revenue__r.BU_Name__c=:BUlst';       
        }
        
        if(fromDate!=null){
          Date fromDate1 =Date.valueOf(fromDate); 
          Date  Datefromvalue =Date.newInstance(fromDate1.year(),fromDate1.month(),1);  
          filter+=' AND Date_Formula__c>=:Datefromvalue';       
        }
             
        if(toDate!=null){
            Date endDate1 =Date.valueOf(toDate);
            Date  Datetovalue =Date.newInstance(endDate1.year(),endDate1.month(),30);
            filter+=' AND Date_Formula__c<=:Datetovalue'; 
        }
        query+=filter+' ORDER BY Date_Formula__c';
        List<Revenue_Report__c> RM =Database.query(query);
        Map<String,Decimal> mrr=new Map<String,Decimal>();
        Map<String,Decimal> Arr=new Map<String,Decimal>();
        for(Revenue_Report__c r:RM){
            String month = r.Revenue_Month__c;
            Decimal amount = r.Revenue_Amount__c!=null?r.Revenue_Amount__c/Math.pow(10, 6):0;
            amount=amount.setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
          if (mrr.containsKey(month)) {
            mrr.put(month, mrr.get(month) + amount);
    } else {
        mrr.put(month, amount);
    }
        }
        System.debug('mrr'+mrr);
        for(String M:mrr.keySet()){
           Decimal Total =mrr.get(M)*12;
           Total = Total.setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);  
           Arr.Put(M,Total); 
        }
        System.debug('arr'+arr);
        
        List<Map<String, Object>> results = new List<Map<String, Object>>();
        for (String month : mrr.keySet()) {
            Map<String, Object> row = new Map<String, Object>();
            row.put('month', month);
            row.put('mrr', mrr.get(month));
            row.put('arr', arr.get(month));
            results.add(row);
        }
        return results;
    }```

[![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.sstatic.net/FY2EcNVo.png


Are you trying to return all the individual records, or just aggregate results? If the former, there's no point returning more than a few hundred records to a user - they are not going to wait for 50000+ records to be loaded into a table in a browser (this will take a loooong time) and certainly won't scroll through it looking for stuff. Better to limit the maximum number and tell the user to apply filters to find data of interest. If handling aggregate data, use SOQL aggregate queries to generate the data for the UI. You cannot get data from a batch (async) to the UI in any sensible way.

Hi @PhilW, thanks for your response, i want show all records aggregate result only not the records, im trying to create reports for all years, if user wants specific year they will add filters. I cant use standard aggregate result. I need to do some calculation from list of records

Hi @PhilW,
I have added screenshot that is showing each month calculation and year calculated amount

If you need to use calculated data, you need to save this to the database, from your batch, as records that this LWC will later show.

Hi @PhilW,
Great Idea, Thanks phil ill try
